# accessing and loading JSON arrays into a .net string[] in silverlight

Tags: c#, json, silverlight

If I have a simple JSON object that is written in the html document space under a script tag (that looks like below), how do I easily load it into Silverlight? I need to load each of the two arrays below into their own String[] in .NET, and it doesn't need to be dynamic as to what arrays in the Player object it loads, it will always just be those two.

Thanks!!!

```
Player = {
    Names: ["name 1","name 2","name 3"],
    Files: ["file 1","file 2","file 3"]
}
```

In Pseudo code:

```
String[] Names = Page.Javascript.Player.Names;
String[] Files = Page.Javascript.Player.Files;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex:

```regex
Player[^;,N]+Names ?: ?(\[[^\]]*\])[^F]+Files ?: ?(\[[^\]]*\])
```

This regual expression will match for the string above. The result groups 1 and 2 will contain your json array with the strings of Names and Files`. Check also this [fiddle](http://fiddle.re/4vnh6).

The next step is just to drop the two groups in a json parser or another regular expression and you have your strings.

Answer (score 0):

If you have more Json to parse, you can use .Net Json helpers in `System.Json dll`

```
var jsonObj = (JsonObject)JsonArray.Parse("{ Names: ['name 1','name 2','name 3'],  Files: ['file 1','file 2','file 3']}");
// You need to cast JsonValue in string
string[] names = (jsonObj["Names"] as JsonArray).Select(j => (string)j).ToArray();
string[] files = (jsonObj["Files"] as JsonArray).Select(j => (string)j).ToArray();
```

You can use `DataContractJsonSerializer` to convert Json in object...

See more http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/cc197957(v=vs.95).aspx